# How getter and setter works in PHP

Tags: php

I need to know how getter and setter will work in PHP.
Because some interviewer asked tricky question about getter and setter.
I have failed to explain.
Can any one help me out?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know better about it ? Maybe use a simple example, it could help you

Answer (score 1):

Getters and setters are used to- at a later stage- make it possible to provide logic when the developer requests or sets a variable.

*If you, for example, want to add a layer of validation to prevent your object from being misused. What if you wanted to make sure that the person’s $name variable is a string variable and not something else? Well, we can simply add that layer of validation to our setter method:*

```
//Set the person's name.
public function setName($name){
   if(!is_string($name)){
       throw new Exception('$name must be a string!');
   }
   $this->name = $name;
}
```

*In the PHP code above, we modified the setter method setName so that it validates the $name variable. Now, if a programmer attempts to set the $name variable to an array or a boolean, our function will throw an Exception. If we wanted to, we could also make sure that the $name variable is not a blank string.*

[Big thanks to this post.](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-getters-and-setters/)

Best of luck on your interview!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15886257)

Comment: @mickmackusa Absolutely true! Better like this?

Comment: Much better.  Thank you for your good SO citizenship.